# Pandas skipping x tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a plot with 15 axis labels and Pandas automatically defaults to showing every other category name.  How do I get it to show ALL of the x-axis labels without skipping items?

```
rows = []
for x in range(0,14):
    rows.append(['a',14-x])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df = df.set_index(0)
df.plot(xticks=df.index)
```

Comment: OK could you post representative data then

Comment: Sure, this data has the same error now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the axes first, create your plot using the keyword `ax` and set the ticks and tick labels manually using `ax.set_xticks()` (http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

rows = []
for x in range(0,14):
    rows.append(['a',14-x])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
# df = df.set_index(0)
df.plot(ax=ax)

ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(list(df[0]))
```

[image]

Comment: It won't let me set the xticks to a string variable "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

Comment: well, i don't know what you are trying to plot, i don't know the ticks nor the labels ... without that, i can't help you

Comment: I think your ValueError comes from you setting the index to the string 'a' for all items by doing `df = df.set_index(0)`

Comment: Yes, my index is a string so I am setting it to 'a' so that it represents the true data.  I want every tick to be 'a' on the bottom.

Comment: I made some edits ... however, i cannot test it for the moment so i don't know if it works

Comment: The labels are now the index.  The labels should be 'a' for each tick.  Thanks for giving it a shot though!

Comment: I understand what you want

Comment: @Chris let me know of it works better now ... seems to work for me.